# Check if line is a dictionary type and print the data?

Tags: python, file, dictionary, python-2.x

I have `.txt` file and its loaded with a lot of text but in between 2-3 paragraphs there is a text like dictionary:

```
somerandomtextinthisline
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
somerandomtextinthislineblasd
asbdjalsdnlasd
dasdjasdkjn
<space>

{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
someranomtextaganinasdlasd
asdasd
```

So what I want to do is read the whole file and grab all `'key2'` from the file and paste it in a file called `result.txt`.

How can I code this?

Comment: This is a family site; watch the language, please?

Comment: It looks like you could just try decoding every line with `json.loads`, and if it works and the result is a dictionary, you're golden.

Comment: This is a family site, not a clairvoyance site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert it to a dictionary (if possible) and check if the parsed line can be indexed using `'key2'`:

```
import ast

with open(filename) as fin:
    for line in fin:
         try:
             parsed = ast.literal_eval(line)
             key2 = parsed['key2']
         except Exception:
             continue
         print(key2)  # I just print it here, you probably need to write it to another file instead
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to match a dictionary in the file:

```
import re
import ast
data = [i.strip('\n') for i in open('filename.txt')]
final_dicts = list(map(ast.literal_eval, [re.sub("\s+", '', i) for i in data if re.findall('\{.*?:.*?,*\}', re.sub("\s+", '', i))]))
```